# Spring Batch - If database access failed while running the JOB

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

we are using remote database
batch tables is also located in remote database

if database access fails or database server become down while running the job then what happens to job which is running in another server

for ex job repository it self unable to update meta data in step execution table after completing the step or chunk or record count which is already processed Due to database access fails in between. then what happen to JOB which is running.

suppose database is fails for 2 hours so job will not able to restart also.

what happens if job starts next time because the job was on running state and job was also unable to update batch tables status as failed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If access is cut of from the job repository's database (ex. pull the plug on the database box), then the job repository will be left in the state of the last chunk's commit.  To restart the job, you would need to manually update the statuses of the previously running step and job so that they are marked correctly as a failed job, then restart the job.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html Start reading from 5.1.5